# How to use map to iterate over list elements in a tibble?

Tags: r, purrr

I have several models stored as a list in a tibble. How do I use `purrr::map()` to iterate functions like `summary()` over this list of models? Ideally, `summary()` should print to the console and not be stored as an additional column in the tibble.

```r
library(tidyverse)

linear_models <- as_tibble(ToothGrowth) %>%
  mutate(dose = factor(dose)) %>%
  group_by(supp) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(models = map(data, ~ lm(len ~ dose, .))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(1, 3)

linear_models
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   supp  models
#>   <fct> <list>
#> 1 VC    <lm>  
#> 2 OJ    <lm>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `map(linear_models$models, summary)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `models` and use `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
linear_models %>%
    pluck(models) %>%
    map(summary)
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
lapply(linear_models$models, summary)
```

Comment: I tried with ```map(summary())``` but only without the brackets (like in your example) it works. Thanks.